# Webpage jumps to the top when scrolling my Logitech G5 in Firefox scroll issue

Tags: windows-7, firefox, logitech-mouse

When I try to use the scroll wheel (either up or down) in Firefox 3, instead of scrolling up or down, the page goes to the very top. The mouse in question is the Logitech G5, and this issue happens with SetPoint versions 4.7 and 4.8.

Comment: What happens if you disable/uninstall the SetPoint software?

Comment: The mouse reverts to standard functions, but I still can't use the mouse wheel in firefox

Comment: I am even more inclined to believe that, as phunehehe said, it is a problem with the drivers, as when I attempted to use VLC, the volume went up no matter which way the scroll wheel was turned. Any thoughts on a fix for this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is a problem with the driver, maybe it's not so well supported yet. I didn't have that problem with windows 7 and firefox. Can you try with another mouse?

Comment: I have a feeling that is the problem, because when I originally installed 7, I had this problem, but it went away for a while after restarted... I just wish it had stayed away.

Answer (score 0):

Try after disabling **use autoscrolling** and **use smooth scrolling** in firefox (Tools>Option>Advanced>General)

Comment: I already tried that, and all disabling autoscrolling did was remove my ability to use the middle-click scrolling.